# How to solve generic type conversion from LinkedTreeMap to ArrayList in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

I want to convert `LinkedTreeMap<*, *>` to `ArrayList<T>`

**Reason**: Why I want to do this conversion because in below example, oldItemList values are type of LinkedTreeMap and I want it to as my Item data class, but again it the whole function should be extension function, because this is common function.

I tried multiple ways, but none of are working. You can put below function in your Android Studio.

```
      @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Bundle.getBaseParcelableArrayList(key: String): ArrayList<T>? {
    return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        val oldItemList: ArrayList<T>? = getParcelableArrayList(key, T::class.java)
        val newItemList = arrayListOf<T>()
        oldItemList?.let {
            for (i in 0 until it.size) {
                val itemMap: LinkedTreeMap<*, *>? = it[i] as? LinkedTreeMap<*, *>
                itemMap?.let {

                    //Convert from itemMap to newItemList and list-values should be clazz type
                }
            }
        }
        return newItemList
    } else {
        getParcelableArrayList(key)
    }
}
```

Accessing like this:

```
val brandData: ArrayList<Item>? = bundle?.getBaseParcelableArrayList(AppConstantV2.BundleKey.BRAND_SCREEN_DATA)
```

Issue:
[image: Issue]

Expectation:

[image]

Comment: But how do you want to convert them, what's your expected logic for this conversion? They are entirely different data types. Could you provide an example of source data and an expected result data?

Comment: Hi @broot Thanks for checking it out, kindly check the edited answer for better understanding.